# What exactly mean X bit depth?

Tags: bitdepth

I am not sure if I understand meaning of “bit depth” in audio.

As I see in many audio applications the audio sample values (when not distorted) are between `minValue = -1.0f;` and `maxValue = 1.0f;`.

I need to know the smallest possible value next to `0.0f` of one sample.

As I suppose “x bit depth” means that one sample can be expressed by 2^16 various values. Am I right?

So does it mean that the smallest possible sample value change is `(maxValue - minValue) / (pow(2.0f, x))` ??? So for 16 bit depth is it `2.0f / pow(2.0f, 16.0f)` ?? Which is `4.6566128742e-10` ?

I have mess in mind, couse I have even problem with simple `float` variable. As I know it has 32 bits. So the biggest value should be 2^31 (and one bit for sign) which is `2147483647`. And for `int` it works, but how is it possible that `float` max value can be `3.40282e+38` ? Which is much more than `2147483647`.

So let’s imagine I have audio with 32 bit depth. So then the smallest possible sample value change is `2.0f / 2147483647.0f`, or maybe `2.0f / 3.40282e+38` ???

And other issue is: should I realy devide `(maxValue - minValue) / (pow(2.0f, x))` - which means bit depth concern to amplitude. Or it concern to gain - which means I should calculete it by `1.0f / (pow(2.0f, x))` ?

Please help me to understand it because my math calculations (a lot of logarithms and powers) gives me a lot of “NaN” and “inf”. So I need to narrow the possible inputs and outputs to avoid such errors. But first I need to understand how to do that.

For any help great thanks in advance.
Best Regards

Comment: "**bit depth**" is an audiophile term for **word width** of the fixed-point words representing the sampled audio signal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bit depth is typically applied to a fixed point representation. 16-bit means the number can go from -2^15 to 2^15-1 so from -32768 to +32767. For 8 bits that would be -128 to +127.

If you normalize to a maximum of 1, your least significant bit (LSB) value is simply the inverse, 1/32678 = 3.0518e-05 for 16 bit or 1/128 = 0.0078125 for 8 bit

Floating point works completely differently. A 32-bit floating point number has a 24 bit mantissa and an 8 bit exponent. So it's basically a 24-bit integer number combined with an 8 bit scale factor that gets "optimized" and recalculated on every floating point operation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic